# Как понять такую конструкцию javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var state in reg) {
    (function (st, state) {
        st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
        st[0].onmouseover = function () {
            st.animate({fill: st.color, stroke: "#ccc"}, 500);
            st.toFront();
        };
        st[0].onmouseout = function () {
            st.animate({fill: "#333", stroke: "#666"}, 500);
            st.toFront();
        };
        if (state == "nsw") {
            st[0].onmouseover();
        }
    })(reg[state], state);
}
```

Разъясните, если не в лом в части что перебирается и как работает эта оберточная функция, особенно ее параметры и что за скобки с параметрами в конце

Спс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var state in reg)
```

Есть какой-то объект reg у которого есть определенное количество свойств скажем так:

```
var reg = {
  method: 1,
  method_else: 2,
....
}
```

Данный цикл переберет все свойства объекта и присвоит его методу state

Далее описывается функция с двумя параметрами, и собственно после своего описания вызывается с определенными параметрами в данном случае (reg[state], state)

Comment: спасибо.
а как понять конструкцию (function (st, state) {
что есть st и каким образом он передается в данную функцию?

     st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";

                                st[0].onmouseover = function () {
                                    st.animate({fill: 'red', stroke: "#ccc"}, 500);
                                    st.toFront();
                                    console.log(state);
                                };

опять же почему манипуляции производятся с индексом 0?

заранее благодарен

Comment: как по мне странный вопрос, так выведите в **консоль** *st* и *reg* и посмотрите что там и откуда. Может это массив какой-то или набор каких-то элементов. Вы же нам не дали полный код и описание функции reg.

Comment: Скорее всего st - это DOM-элемент. Исторически сложилось, что в результате выборки DOM-элементов по тому или иному селектору возвращается массив (что логично и правильно).
Поэтому просто идет обращение к первому элементу массива DOM-элементов, подходящих какому-то селектору.

Answer (score 1):

Эта "оберточная" функция играет архиважную роль -- в таком ее применении для каждого элемента объекта в цикле создается и сохраняется локальная область видимости переменных. Это нужно для того, чтобы корректно повесить обработчики событий мыши на каждый элемент.
Если такую "обертку" не применять, то событие повеситься только одно - на последний элемент.
Более подробно об этом можно прочитать здесь: [Замыкания](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure)